# Maillog /bin/sh: /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda: No such file or directory 4.2.1

Tags: centos, plesk, dovecot

I just moved to a new server with **Plesk** pre-installed on it, my sites work now but when I try to send mails I get the following error:

> Mar  5 13:43:14 www postfix/qmgr[2271]: 9351512650BA:
>   from=, size=572, nrcpt=1 (queue active)    Mar  5
>   13:43:14 www postfix-local[3080]: postfix-local:
>   from=info@[MY_DOMAIN].nl, to=servers@[MY_DOMAIN].nl,
>   dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames    Mar  5 13:43:14 www
>   postfix/pipe[3079]: 9351512650BA: to=,
>   relay=plesk_virtual, delay=1307, delays=1307/0.04/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0,
>   status=deferred (temporary failure. **Command output: /bin/sh:
>   /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda: No such file or directory** 4.2.1
>   Message can not be delivered at this time )

I have been looking for over an hour but I have not found a fix yet.
The directory `/usr/lib/dovecot` does not exists, the directory `/usr/lib64/dovecot` does exists.

The server runs on Centos.

**SOLVED:** I found out that I copied the full mail directories, including the config  files. I removed the mailboxes and moved over the mail directories without config files. Now the mailbox works again.
So for everybody with the same problem when moving. Don't copy your mail config files.

Answer (score 1):

Various options exist:

1. `ln -s /usr/lib64/dovecot/dovecot-lda /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda`,
2. Edit your `postfix/master.cf` file and change the `/usr/lib/dovecot` path to `/usr/lib64/dovecot`,
3. Install a 32-bit version of Dovecot on that box.

All have their disadvantages, the best thing is to coordinate with the people who wrote the software that manages the email config and let them know your trouble.